# Can I make the program ask for sys arguements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on an encoder project with some code provided from someone else. The program asks for you to define an infile and name for the outfile when you run the program. For example, python3 main.py infile.txt outfile.txt. I would like to have the program start and ask you to define these inside the program rather than parsing the arguments beforehand. For instance, it asks you the infile name, then the outfile name then it just runs. I can provide any other code you may need to see.

Here's the arguements code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage : %s infile outfile" % sys.argv[0],file=sys.stderr)
        raise SystemExit(1)

    in_filename = sys.argv[1]
    out_filename = sys.argv[2]
```

Comment: You mean like `in_filename = input("Enter input filename: ")`?

Comment: @DaveCosta I don't totally agree about the duplicate, since in Python 3 `input()` has a different meaning that `input()` in Python 2 (Python 3's `input()` corresponds to Python 2's `raw_input()`).